# Converting an excel adjacency matrix to be readable in python

Tags: python, excel, networkx

just needed a bit of help with converting an excel spreadsheet matrix to a form that is readable by python's networkx module. I have tried using xlrd, but I have no clue. Please help, let me know if I need to make the question more specific.
the code I have used thus far is:

```
import xlrd

loc = 'C:\Users\kchen\Desktop\UNSW UNI\Honours\Publishing papers\EVC\Brain matrix\brain 1 matrix.xlsx'

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

assert isinstance(sheet.nrows, object)
print(sheet.nrows)

loc = 'C:\Users\kchen\Desktop\UNSW UNI\Honours\Publishing papers\EVC\Brain matrix\brain 1 matrix.xlsx'

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# For row 0 and column 0
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

# Extracting number of columns
print(sheet.ncols)
```

Comment: show the attempt that you made with xlrd

Comment: import xlrd

loc = 'C:\Users\kchen\Desktop\UNSW UNI\Honours\Publishing papers\EVC\Brain matrix\brain 1 matrix.xlsx'

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

assert isinstance(sheet.nrows, object)
print(sheet.nrows)

loc = 'C:\Users\kchen\Desktop\UNSW UNI\Honours\Publishing papers\EVC\Brain matrix\brain 1 matrix.xlsx'

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# For row 0 and column 0
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

# Extracting number of columns
print(sheet.ncols)

Comment: Not sure why it came out like that, but essentially I need to upload the excel file and produce an adjacency matrix from it. I then need it to calculate Eigenvector centrality values from that. I have tried various scripts and codes but nothing is working.

Comment: edit it into the original question not a comment

Comment: I uploaded it now